# New Domain: Cannot synchronize new domain way after 72 hour tenant window has closed

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-domain-services, azureadconnect

We have a tenant: im-one.com, which behind the scenes has changed its internal active directory.  We tore down the old domain, disconnected the old domain, waited the requisite 72 hours, and still cannot get the new domain to synchronize.  We cannot even start over with a new domain on the Azure tenant because we cannot delete users (a prerequisite step) because the tenant still thinks there is a synchronization disable pending on our end.  Can someone from Microsoft fix this for us?  This is ridiculous for a tenant with just a few users to wait literally days for a simple domain re-establishment to occur.

Comment: Sync what, exactly? Synching on premises to Office 365? To Azure? Give us more details. Also, we're not Microsoft, so why don't you reach out to them?

Comment: You will need to raise a support request with Microsoft